# How do I mirror Django's email validation on the front end

Tags: javascript, django, validation, email, django-rest-auth

I am using the user registration url from django rest auth:

```py
urlpatterns = [
   #...
   path("registration/", include("dj_rest_auth.registration.urls")),
   #...
]
```

This route includes email validation. However, I would like to prevalidate addresses before I send them to the server.

Using a simple regex on the front end allows addresses through that dj_rest_auth doesn't:

```js
/^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/.test(email)
```

Will allow, for example, `a@b.c` which django will reject.

I would like to match the server side validation as closely as possible with javascript. What regex does dj_rest_auth use?

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting length like this

```js
var isValidEmail = (email) => /[a-z0-9]+@[a-z]+\.[a-z]{2,3}/.test(email)

console.log(isValidEmail('a@b.c'))
console.log(isValidEmail('someone@test.com'))
```

Comment: Pretty sure that would be too restrictive. There are four letter TLDs like name and info

Comment: You can adjust the length, with regex to get your desired result.